# pandas `to_html()` - how to make the entire column header colored and curved (left top and right top corners)

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(index = ["Name1", "Name2", "Total"])
data["A"] = [1,2,3]
data["B"] = [2,1,3]
data.index.name = "Index"
data.columns.name = ""
data
```

And I want to make the entire header (including column index name) colored in blue and curved (only the first and the last top header). Currently this is my solution:

```
data.style.set_table_styles([{
    'selector': '.index_name',
    'props': 'background-color: blue; border-top-left-radius: 10px'}])
```

And this is the output:
[image]

The output should be that all the column headers are blue (6 cells under "Name1" row) and only "columns.name" and "B" cells are curved, while now "Index" is also curved).
How can I do that (also for cases where index has more than one level - how in that case make formatting for the top left cell)?